# How to use hydro and groovy Both together?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to use both hydro and groovy ros desktop but when i use below commad to change ros hydro to ros groovy not happened, what's problem?

#source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120616/how-to-use-hydro-and-groovy-both-together?/) by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-01-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) on 2014-01-22**:
Could you clarify your problem?

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-01-22**:
I was written my codes in groovy, now i install hydro but i can't run my codes now,
i want to run my code on groovy but, by default ros run it on hydro...
what's problem?
How can i do?

**Comment by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) on 2014-01-22**:
Try to explain exactly what you are running, how, and what the errors are. If you do not give any detail, we cannot help you.

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-01-22**:
i want to run hector_slam on groovy but always ros run it on hydro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

Note that you might not necessarily be able to run any Groovy program on Hydro (Hydro program on Groovy) but assuming it does, you'd need to build it with your target installation sourced. To clarify, an example where your package is in the directory ~/catkin_workspace:

Every time you want to switch installations you'll need to do all of these:

- source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash or source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
- cd ~/catkin_workspace
- rm /devel -r
- rm /build -r
- catkin_make
- source devel/setup.bash
- rosrun my_package do_cool_stuff

Note that you need to remove /devel and /build (actually probably just /devel, but I'm not sure about that one) because it contains references to the current installation, ie it is Groovy or Hydro specific.

-Tim

---

Originally posted by [Tim Sweet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5998/tim-sweet/) with karma: 267 on 2014-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-01-22**:
Thank Tim for your good answer... :-)
but i never use catkin make, i always use rosmake to make anything in ros, it cause something difference?

**Comment by [Tim Sweet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5998/tim-sweet/) on 2014-01-24**:
I've personally never used rosmake, but you should be able to just substitute it in there

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I'm not sure understand your problem properly. but you must attention when you make a package in Groovy and run it you can't use it in hydro. before using that you must make this in hydro and take notice, some msgs and stack are changed  in hydro.

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-01-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-01-22**:
Thanks for your time Hamid.